# Python savetxt header

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to add a header to my text file when I'm writing an array to it:

`np.savetxt('output.txt', array, header = str(dimension))`

but it looks like by default Python adds `#` in front of the header. Is there anyway I can get rid of that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), `comment` is prepended to `header`.

So, try

```
np.savetxt('output.txt', array, header=str(dimension), comments='')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 np.savetxt(BASEPATH+ r'keywordsarray2.txt', df1.values,
                          fmt='%4.d', header=str(df1.columns))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question at all.